# Android date picker as no backdate can be selected, only today and future date

Tags: java, android, date

i do have one date picker as i just want to make it only can select today's date and future date, no back date. Need some guidelines on how it can be done, maybe spinner can do that?

```
//start date
    TableRow r8 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tvStartDate = new TextView(this);
    tvStartDate.setText("Start Date: ");
    final EditText etStartDate = new EditText(this);
    etStartDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar dateNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = dateNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = dateNow.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = dateNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dp;
            dp = new DatePickerDialog(AddPetActivity.this, new OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                    etStartDate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dp.setTitle("Select Date");
            dp.show();
        }
    });
    r8.addView(tvStartDate);
    r8.addView(etStartDate);
    tb.addView(r8);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the dialog's date picker and set it's min/max dates like so:

```
 dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dateNow.getTimeInMillis());
```

Note that when setting a minimum date for a picker it must be before the selected date of the picker, otherwise you get an `IllegalArgumentException` (same goes for max date of course).

Comment: This code should work, make sure my snippet is before the call to `show`

Comment: i modify your code as dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dateNow.getTimeInMillis() -1000); then it works